# Search one file into another, print match and next line

Tags: bash, awk, grep

and this is my question:
I have two files, one with names (about 1k lines, and no repetitions)

File_Names

```
A
C
F
```

And a second file with names and data (about 100k lines, and no repetitions)

File_Data

```
A
Data_A
B
Data_B
C
Data_C
D
Data_D
E
Data_E
F
Data_F
```

And I need to search from the Names into the Data files, printing the findings along with the next line.

Something like:

```
A
Data_A
C
Data_C
F
Data_F
```

I have the part for finding the Names into the Data files, but still can't print the next line

```
awk 'FNR==NR{
        a[$1]++;
        next}
        a[$1]
' File_Names File_Data
```

This returns

```
A
C
F
```

That's the part of the code I've keeped, because with this I've tried other codes like

```
awk 'FNR==NR{
    a[$0]=FNR;i=FNR;next}
($0 in a){
    t=$0;
    getline;b[a[t]]=$0}
END{
    for(k=1;k<=i;k++)print b[k]
}'
```

And adding/removing lines like:

```
- {x=NR+1}(NR<=x){print}
- {getline;print;}
```

Also tried using grep with

```
grep -f File_Names File_Data
```

But still nothing. Sorry for the repeated question, but the solutions avaliable aren't working for me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Curious why your `grep` solution didn't work. Did you perchance generate one or both of these files on MS Windows? Stray invisible CR characters at the ends of your lines might cause `File_Names` lines not to be matched, if the `File_Data` file was generated in unix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`grep`** solution:

```
grep -A1 --no-group-separator -xf File_Names File_Data
```

- `A num` - print `num` lines of trailing context after matching lines
- `--no-group-separator` - do not print a separator between groups of lines

The output:

```
A
Data_A
C
Data_C
F
Data_F
```

Comment: I can't imagine any solution will be faster than this. Though I'd likely go for `-F` instead of `-W`, since the filenames are likely fixed strings, not regexps.

Comment: thx for your answers, that worked. The File_Names had a \t after each line, and that was the reason of everything failing. I removed it with sed and this grep worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple awk solution:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} $0 in a{print; getline; print}' File_Names File_Data
A
Data_A
C
Data_C
F
Data_F
```

This is potentially limiting in terms of the size of the `a` array in memory, though I expect 1000 keys won't be a huge problem.  It also has a potential race in that if you have a line of data that is also a filename, output will be wonky. You can protect from that by insuring that filenames are only checked on odd-numbered lines in `File_Data`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} FNR%2 && $0 in a{print; getline; print}' File_Names File_Data
```

Note that you could do the same thing in bash alone, without depending on awk, though it wouldn't perform nearly as well:

```
$ declare -A FN; while IFS= read -r x; do FN[$x]=1; done < File_Names
$ while IFS= read -r x; do IFS= read -r y; [[ -n "${FN[$x]}" ]] && printf '%s\n%s\n' "$x" "$y"; done < File_Data
A
Data_A
C
Data_C
F
Data_F
```

This depends on bash version 4 or above for `declare -A` (the associative array). The first loop populates keys of the `$FN` array with filenames, and the second loop steps through the loop checking for key existence, printing results if a key is found.

Comment: With bash, you can slurp the File_Names with `mapfile -t FN < File_Names` instead of a while-read loop

Comment: @glennjackman - sure, but that puts the input into the ***values*** of the array, rather than the *index*. The test, `[[ -n "${FN[$x]}" ]]` ] checks for the data's existence in the index. Is there as quick a lookup for array values?